# What does `Sl` refer to in tabular?

Tags: tables

I am looking for info about `Sl` in `tabular` environment "declarations".

Where can I read more about it?

Comment: `S` columns are numeric columns from the `siunitx` package

Comment: if this was a "fake" question intended for a self answer it is best to mention that to save other people answering and also it is really not very clear as I would guess that in the vast majority of cases `Sl` denotes a siunitx S column followed by an l column, not the construct that you suggest in your answer.

Comment: It was not. I found the answer afterwards.

Comment: Note that for `siunitx` I'm likely to make the letter user-selectable for the next major release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is from the `cellspace` package. [See the doc](http://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/cellspace/cellspace.pdf).

Comment: depends on. it can also be two columns, first is `S` from `siunitx` and `l` is standard column type.

Comment: In this case, one can use the letter `C` as a prefix for ‘cellspace’d columns, or any letter you please since version 1.7, thanks to the  new key `column=` some letter.